# checkbox - change notification

Tags: windows, winapi, checkbox

What notification code is sent with the wm_command message to the dialog box procedure when a check box changes state?

And more importantly, where would I look in the msdn to find the notification codes for various controls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that Check boxes and Radio buttons are Buttons. So they send click and double click messages, `BN_CLICKED` and `BN_DOUBLECLICKED`.

If you use MFC, then you can examine the `check` state with [CButton::GetCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tba1y6f%28VS.80%29.aspx) method.
Otherwise you send the [BM_GETCHECK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775986%28VS.85%29.aspx) message to the control: `SendMessage(button_handle, BM_GETCHECK, 0, 0);`

`SendMessage` can return

- `BST_CHECKED` Button is checked.
- `BST_INDETERMINATE`  Button is grayed, indicating an indeterminate state
  (applies only if the button has the `BS_3STATE` or `BS_AUTO3STATE` style).
- `BST_UNCHECKED`  Button is cleared
- If the button has a style other than those listed, the return value is zero.

If you use the Visual Studio, the easiest way to get a list of events/messages a control can send is to go to Resource/Design view, right click a control and select *Events*.

For a list of common controls see: [Control Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773169%28VS.85%29.aspx)
(in the page you'll see a popup menu with the controls if you hover the cursor on the *Control Library* link)

Comment: But OnClicked event doesn't respose for `((CButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CB))->SetCheck(BST_CHECKED);`

Comment: @Zhang, to change the value of the check box programmatically, instead of `SetCheck()`, use `((CButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CB))->SendMessage(BM_SETCHECK, BST_CHECKED);`

Answer (score 2):

It's [`BN_CLICKED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775949(VS.85).aspx#using_checkboxes). The bottom of the page links to the button messages.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had tried that but made a () mistake.

What do you mean by 'The bottom of the page links to the button messages'?  What page?  I see if I knew enough to look up BN_CLICKED, I could have gotten to 'Button Messages'.  For example, if I want to find out about list box messages, where would I start?